# Turn 1.5k to integer ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How do I turn `"1.5k"` into `1500` or `"1,766"` into `"1766"` with ruby or rails?

Thanks!

Comment: check this: https://github.com/zedtux/human_size_to_number

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using ruby without rails.

```
n = "1,200.5k"
n = n.to_s.gsub(/,+/, '')
n = (n[-1] == 'k' ? n[0...-1].to_f * 1000 : n).to_i
puts n
```

Comment: hanks for suggestion. For thr 1.5k, it can easily be 1.5m and 1.5b... how can i deal with all the difference

Comment: You can write parser for each case, like `n = (n[-1] == 'm' ? n[0...-1].to_f * 1_000_000 : n).to_i`

Answer (score 2):

As for the case "1.5k" you can write a quick method that, if the `.to_i()` fails, looks for a `k` as the last character. You can get the last character by doing `num_str[-1, 1]`, where `num_str` is the original string.

For the other case, I would recommend looking into the [money](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money) gem. `num = Money.parse("1,766")`.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. For thr 1.5k, it can easily be 1.5m and 1.5b... how can i deal with all the difference

Comment: You can do it case by case ('b', 'm', 'k').